# Errors with BigQuery Sink Connector Configuration

Tags: docker-compose, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to ingest data from MySQL to BigQuery. I am using Debezium components running on Docker for this purpose.

Anytime I try to deploy the BigQuery sink connector to Kafka connect, I am getting this error:

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nFailed to construct GCS client: Failed to access JSON key file\nAn unexpected error occurred while validating credentials for BigQuery: Failed to access JSON key file\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

It shows it's an issue with the service account key (trying to locate it)

I granted the service account BigQuery Admin and Editor permissions, but the error persists.

This is my BigQuery connector configuration file:

```
{
    "name": "kcbq-connect1",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
      "tasks.max" : "1",
      "topics" : "kcbq-quickstart1",
      "sanitizeTopics" : "true",
      "autoCreateTables" : "true",
      "autoUpdateSchemas" : "true",
      "schemaRetriever" : "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.retrieve.IdentitySchemaRetriever",
      "schemaRegistryLocation":"http://localhost:8081",
      "bufferSize": "100000",
      "maxWriteSize":"10000",
      "tableWriteWait": "1000",
      "project" : "dummy-production-overview",
      "defaultDataset" : "debeziumtest",
      "keyfile" : "/Users/Oladayo/Desktop/Debezium-Learning/key.json"
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try creating another service account Key and try loading it again ? For reference: 
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: I needed to mount the service account key in my local directory to the Kafka connect container. That was how I was able to solve the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to mount the service account key in my local directory to the Kafka connect container. That was how I was able to solve the issue. Thank you :)